# H2 parsedatetime of CSV file

Tags: database, h2

I have a csv file that need to import using CSVREAD. The issue is that it has date time format in a different way so a need to parse it.Can some one give me an example of how i am supposed to do it?

I tried: merge into MESSAGE (MESG_DATE_FROM,MESG_DATE_TO,MESG_DISPLAY_SEQ,MESG_TIME_DELAY,MESG_ID,REASONTYPE_MAJOR) SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('MESSAGE_0.csv');

This querys are made programatically so they cannot be handmade. The problem is that some columns are datetime type and are in a different datetime format from the one in H2, at the moment of parsing i have no precise way of determining which columns will be datetime so i cannot easily put a PARSEDATETIME and the CSV file doesnt contains any column names or info, just the values. Like this: 
2011-11-18 00.00.00.00,2030-12-31 00.00.00.00,1,20000,1,0, 
...
...

An Sql file will be generated to load this CSV to each table but it seems i need to know if a column is of TIMESTAMP type to add PARSEDATETIME(MESG_DATE_FROM,'yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss.uu') as MESG_DATE_FROM to the sql.

In DB2 we could use a timestampformat=YYYY-MM-DD HH.MM.SS.UU in the merge query so this was done in a default way for tables. Is there anythis similar in H2?

Comment: I updated my question with more information.

Comment: If you don't know which columns are datetime, then how did you create the table? Did you use varchar for every column?

Comment: Tables and Columns are autogenerated by code and i can't control if a column will be of certain type or a new column is added. If it helps now my CSV does have the column names. But as of right now the only way i can imagine of adding the PARSEDATETIME(MESG_DATE_FROM,'yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss.uu') as MESG_DATE_FROM is to ask each column for its type at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is not possible. There is no way to change the "global" timestamp format in H2 (as you can do in DB2).

I think you will need to either

- construct the query based on the column types of each column, using `PARSEDATETIME` where appropriate, or
- modify the CSV file to use the same timestamp format as H2 uses, which is the format defined in the [JDBC specification, under SQL escape sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13157_01/wlevs/docs30/jdbc_drivers/sqlescape.html#wp1055124): `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.f...]`, or
- provide a patch for H2 to support the "global" timestamp format.